# Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator: How to refresh page

Tags: android, xaml, emulation, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

With Visual Studio 2015's Android emulator using Xamarin Forms, is it possible to refresh a page after a XAML change?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to rebuild and redeploy the app.